# how to create ms-access like continuous subforms (widgets) in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, pyqt

I'm thinking of porting my access application to Qt. I am interested to learn how to do continouos subforms, sub custom widgets for presenting/editing/inserting data from recordset in a verically scrollable non datagrid fashion. Meaning I could put button, label, combo, lineEdit... whatever, for every record.

I like QTableView and delegates. I just don't know if it could be modified to fully emulate access subform.

Sidequestion(maybe the same answer)... how do they DO those continuous forms in access under the hood.

thanks

... not real application data in that example recordset

[image: design]

[image: the works]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to your question, showing what you want, for those of us not familiar with Access?

Comment: PS now that your reputation is over 10, you will be able to add an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt MVC is probably the best/easiest answer for your question ( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html ), and with QTableView you should be able to achieve what you want.

Another solution could be: if you have a fix set of column items in every row you could simply design a QWidget with the contents of the row and paste your items (rows) into a QVerticalLayout.

Although I would sugget to try with MVC because that's the preferred way and in this case you could even port it to use QML UI if you want (while you can use the same data classes for the 'backend'). QML is definitely the best approach for (even slightly) animated UIs, and it's mature enough to use it already (it's part of Qt 4.8 and will be the 'star' of Qt 5).

Comment: thanks, it's not definitive answer. but in this phase of my project it's not mission critical. i'll use MVC, standard views and delegates. and after i really get to know that i'll try custom item views an such. i just thought that Qt has simpler, more obvious solution to my problem

Comment: I think the 'simpler, more obvious' solution is the QVerticalLayout + custom QWidget based solution I've mentioned. It probably requires less code to write, but still I would advice to use MVC because it's a more reusable and more robust solution, but it requires a deeper architecture knowledge about how you should use MVC with Qt (and probably a bit more code as well).

Comment: I just fount this official Qt Example / Demo which can help you: [http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-spreadsheet.html](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-spreadsheet.html) - although it uses QTableWidget and not QTableView.